# Combining jQuery Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two Ajax requests that I am wanting to combine together into one. I'm having trouble figuring how to do this as one is using `$.ajax()` and another is using `$.get()`.

As I'm fairly new to Ajax, this is causing me much pain. If you could help, it would me much appreciated.

**Ajax Request #1**

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
    data: "page="+page,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#gallery_container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
        {
            gallery_show();
            loading_hide();
            $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
        });
    }
});
```

**Ajax Request #2**

```
$.get("new_arrivals_data.php",{imgs: value}, function(data){
    $("#gallery_container").html(data);
});
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually both GETs `$.get` is short hand for `$.ajax({ type:'GET'`.

So combining them might work depending on your server's response:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: "new_arrivals_data.php",
    data: {page:page, imgs: value},
    success: function(msg)
    {
        gallery_show();
        loading_hide();
        $("#gallery_container").html(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: It was mostly combining the two data calls that I wasn't sure about. Although reading the other answers, I start to wonder if I'm doing it right. It's for an image gallery. The first code is for the pagination. The second is for number of images per page. Right now they are both in a single php file as I assumed that was needed. Am I wrong?

Comment: Could you shed some light on how to deal with the `function(msg)` and `function(data)` in the Ajax calls? I'm not even sure what they are referring to. I know that in the php file for the first one, there is `$msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>"`, but I can't see any reference to `data` in the php file for the second call. What do they mean?

Comment: msg or data is what is returned from the server. We can name it whatever we want, which is why there are two different names, msg and data, for the same thing.

Comment: So those names will be what is `echo` from the php file. Not a php variable.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're looking for, but Ajax Request #2 is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "get_images.php",
    data: {imgs: value},
    success: function(data){
        $("#imgTray").html(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just 'combine' requests - you'll still need to make two separate requests to each of these URLs. Since by default, ajax requests are asynchronous, you can fire them both almost simultaneously (if one doesn't depend on the other. As marko points out in the comments, if they *are* dependent, you could force the requests to be synchronous. [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) has an `async` property.).

```
if(condition){
    makeRequest1();
    makeRequest2();
}
```

Also `$.get()` is simply a convenience method for `$.ajax()` with certain options preset (such as using `GET` as the request type).

Comment: You can also force the calls to be synchronous with the "async:false"-parameter to the "ajax"-call.

Comment: @marko Sure, that's why I mentioned that they're async by default. Though I see your point - with my choice of words it seems like there'd be no way to make the requests in sequence if they were dependent. I'll fix that.